# iPhone or iPod Touch as test device

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipod-touch, ipod

I'd like to get a device for testing iPhone apps that I can wipe at anytime.  A 1stG iPhone or iPod Touch is ideal.  With an iPod touch, I'll pay for OS upgrades.  However, on eBay, iPhones are going for $300+.  Used iPod Touches are about $150-$200.

I want to avoid paying a monthly fee for the iPhone, which means I'll be limited to wifi for Internet connectivity.  That should be fine.

Is there a cheaper way to get a test device or any other suggestions?

Comment: Does this question belong on StackOverflow?
I don't see how this relates to programming directly, more about acquisition of goods.

Comment: It's a valid StackOverflow question, because only other developers are going to be able to answer it.  For example, can you develop on a unactivated phone?  Who else is going to know this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are registered iPhone Developer (which I'm assuming you are since you're trying to build to a physical device), you do not have to pay for OS upgrades for the iPod Touch. The OS upgrades are apart of the iPhone SDK.

If you're looking for an iPod Touch I would recommend either a 2nd Generation, or 3rd Generation model. Both should be fine for average app testing. Just keep in mind that there are a couple device limitations compared against the iPhone 3GS. No compass, GSM Controller, or camera (video or pictures (yet))...

You can purchase an iPhone either from ebay or a third party without having to use a cell phone carrier. Your only limitation would being unable to use the GSM connection (carrier provided).

Comment: Yikes!  You're right - I certainly need the camera/video part, which means I'll have to go with an iPhone.  But why do you recommend 3rd generation?  If many people are using a 2nd G iPhone and I'm always testing on 3GS, I'll never know the horrible 2nd G experience those customers might be having and I could have fixed if I'd tested against that model.

Comment: @ 4thSpace - The minor differences between the 2nd and 3rd Gen iPod Touches are not many. Faster processor speed 533 vs 600, 128MB of RAM vs 256, also the 3rd generation has a faster and more powerful graphics processor. As to your 2nd statement. Yes, you will never know the performance difference. Try and develop your apps with the lowest common denominator in mind (performance wise), develop you apps with efficiency and performance in mind and you'll be on the right track. Regardless of what device your app runs on.

Comment: Thanks.  All and all, do you believe getting a test device (probably will need to be an iPhone) is a good way to go?  Especially if user device issues are encountered that do not occur on the developer's main/only iPhone.

Comment: @4thSpace - I got an iPod Touch exactly for that reason. My lowest baseline is now pretty low. (Anyone with iPod Touch 2nd generation and OS 3.0 will be able to run my apps. iPad is a different story now that it's out...)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the emulator which comes with XCode.
It's not ideal (far from it!), but at least you won't have to spend any money with it.

Comment: Nope - that certainly won't help you with code signing issues or having an app crash on just a few user devices and not others.

Comment: The emulator is severely limited, but while you're getting familiar with XCode and Objective-c it's not a bad tool to have. If I had the choice to use it or use nothing I wouldn't be so quick to run away from it.

Answer (score 0):

You could give [Device Anywhere](http://www.deviceanywhere.com) a try.  My company used that service for a while and it seemed to meet our needs.

As an independent developer the price may be too much.

Comment: I was also going to add they have a free trial.  Except its only for 3 hours.  Geez.

Answer (score 0):

On this [site](http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/) you can download any version of the iPhone/iPod touch firmware, thus no need to pay 10$ for the upgrade.

Comment: Hmmm, jailbroken?  Not interested.

Comment: I question the legality of such a service.

Comment: No need for a jailbroken phone